# this code not woking ? display : none and block not working onec again

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did not know why is it.
i found answer but i need reason why because.
I'm creating a tab .

Im also tried,

```
  document.write(x[i]'<style>display:none<style');
```

and

```
  document.getElementId(x[i]).styly.display="none";
```

It is working

```
        var x = new Array("nf", "sc", "rf", "gd");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               var z = document.getElementById(x[i]);
                z.style.display = "block";
            }
```

it also working

```
        var x = new Array("nf", "sc", "rf", "gd");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

              var y = document.getElementById(x[i]);           
             y.style.display = "none";
            }
```

it is not working

```
      function tab(a)
      {
        var b =a;
        var x = new Array("nf", "sc", "rf", "gd");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
          if (i == b)
            {
            var z = document.getElementById(x[i]);
            z.style.display = "block";
            }
         else {
            var y = document.getElementById(x[i]);           
            y.style.display = "none";
            }
      }
```

```html
     <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
       <td>
       <input id="Button1" type="button" value="sec 1" onclick="tab(0)" /> 
       </td>
       <td>
       <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Sec 2" onclick="tab(1)"/> 
       </td>
       <td>
       <input id="Button3" type="button" value="sec3" onclick="tab(2)"/> 
       </td>
       <td>
       <input id="Button4" type="button" value="sec4" onclick="tab(3)"/> 
       </td>
    </tr>
     </table>
     <div id="nf">It is sec 1</div>
     <div id="sc">It is sec 2</div>
     <div id="rf">It is sec 3</div>
     <div id="gd">It is sec 4</div>
```

what im do fist change display properties in css that working. And secound change in css properties is not working while code in same function.

both function i do separate function it working
but
if I do both at same function it not working.

I got ans to create tab on below link but I did not know why it is not working.
if any one know, please explain to me

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: `var a = b;`? variable `b` doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please first read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I see you tried `styly.display = "none"` which is a typo, maybe try `style.display = "none"`.

Comment: thanks for your replay var b = a;  i typed wrong in stack overflow . now i edit this. var b=a but is not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable b is not initialized. Where is it from?

```js
function tab(a) {
    var x = new Array("nf", "sc", "rf", "gd");
    // if you already have an array use the length of it
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (i == a) {
        var z = document.getElementById(x[i]);
        z.style.display = "block";
     } else {
        var y = document.getElementById(x[i]);           
        y.style.display = "none";
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
   <td>
   <input id="Button1" type="button" value="sec 1" onclick="tab(0)" /> 
   </td>
   <td>
   <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Sec 2" onclick="tab(1)"/> 
   </td>
   <td>
   <input id="Button3" type="button" value="sec3" onclick="tab(2)"/> 
   </td>
   <td>
   <input id="Button4" type="button" value="sec4" onclick="tab(3)"/> 
   </td>
</tr>
 </table>
 <!-- make all other than the first tab display none at first -->
 <div id="nf">It is sec 1</div>
 <div id="sc" style="display: none">It is sec 2</div>
 <div id="rf" style="display: none">It is sec 3</div>
 <div id="gd" style="display: none">It is sec 4</div>
```

Comment: kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze thank for replay but var a= b; im typed wrong.but i do it in stack over. Now i edit that. even var b= a; is not working

Comment: @siddhu why would you even create a new variable for a? that makes no sense. You can try my example it's working.

Comment: yes creating new variable make no sense . thank you @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze